# Create view using many tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I used this syntax to create a view from a table :

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS 
    SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE condition
```

I will create a view from many table relied. For Example  I have two tables :

- Person : id, first_name, last_name, Age, City_id
- City : id, city_name, zip_code

I try this request to create a view (first_name,last_name,city_name) from the two tables, but it does not work :

```
CREATE VIEW view AS 
    SELECT 
        first_name, 
        last_name, 
        (SELECT city_name FROM City where City_id=id ) 
    FROM Person.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Change the name of the view. You are using 'view' and that's a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

You should use a join:

```
CREATE VIEW person_city AS
    select 
        first_name,
        last_name,
        city_name
     from Person p
     join City c
     on p.city_id = c.city_id
```

Notice that I have renamed the view in my example SQL.  Using reserved words such as `view` for db object names is generally not advised, however if it must be named `view` you can always use backticks.

Comment: Thanks for your help CREATE VIEW person_city AS
    select 
        first_name,
        last_name,
        c.city_name
     from Person p
     join City c
     on p.city_id = c.id

Comment: @user2944302 Glad I could help!  Please let me know if you have additional questions.  If one of these answers solved your issue please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW person_view AS
    SELECT 
        first_name, last_name
    FROM
        Person
            JOIN
        City ON City.id = Person.City_id
```